# Why does SHA512 start with "1"?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, provable-security, entropy, sha-512

I just used this

```
hashed = str(bin(int(hashlib.sha512(input1).hexdigest(), 16))[2:])
```

and then just see that the first bit is always 1

I have noticed quite an odd pattern, that all SHA512 output's first bit is always `1`, while the others are random. Why is this?

Does this mean that SHA512 only provides 511 bits of security?

Does this prove that SHA512 is not a random oracle?

Comment: Hmmm, I happen to have a set of SHA512 hashes lying around; going through them, I don't see any 'first bit is always 1' behavior.  Are you sure that's what you're seeing (and not, say, that your hashing utility always puts a fixed string in front of the output hash or something)?

Comment: ```for i in `seq 1 10` ; do head -c16 </dev/urandom | openssl sha512 ; done``` — all 512 bits look random to me.

Comment: I believe it doesn't: I just used this `hashed = str(bin(int(hashlib.sha512(input1).hexdigest(), 16))[2:])` , and then just see that the first bit is always 1

Comment: No, not the `HEX`, the binary. The first binary unit, not the hex. A SHA512 output is just 512 bits of [0,1], and the first bit is constantly 1

Comment: This is because you encode it as an int before making it a binary ascii string. That conversion throws away any starting 0 bits (i.e. 011 = 11 in binary).

Comment: @cryptonoob400 The bin function call does not zero pad the output to 512 bits; Is the string you're examining even 512 bits long?

Comment: @EllaRose No I have just tested it up to 22 bits.

Comment: Go back and reread @DiscobarMolokai's response. You are silently discarding any leading zeroes with your series of conversions, and half the resulting bit-strings you're looking at are 512 bits long, a quarter of them are 511 bits long, an eighth of them are 510 bits long, etc. TL;DR, there *are* zeroes there, you're just not printing them because 0b00000001 == 0b1.

Comment: @cryptonoob400 is that VB6 code?

Comment: Note that there is simply no reason at all to convert a SHA-256 result into a number. These kind of unneeded conversions are often the first to blame when it comes to interpreting unexpected results. I'd guess at least 30/40% of the issues regarding crypto on StackOverflow are due to this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 4):

> I have noticed quite an odd pattern, that all SHA512 output's first bit is always 1, while the others are random. Why is this?

You’re doing (read: coding) it wrong, which made you interpret things wrong. See, all SHA-512 that start (in hex notation) with `0` to `7` will have a ZERO as first bit, all others starting with `8` to `F` will start with a ONE as first bit.

Simplest example: take the SHA-512 of the letter `a`, and you’ll have a hash starting with a ZERO-bit.

```
SHA512("a") = 1f40fc92da241694750979ee6cf582f2d5d7d28e18335de05abc54d0560e0f5302860c652bf08d560252aa5e74210546f369fbbbce8c12cfc7957b2652fe9a75
```

In binary that becomes…

```
HEX:    1    f |    4    0 |    f    c | …
BIN: 0001 1111 | 0100 0000 | 1111 1100 | …
     ^ ZERO!!!
```

So, as you can see, you‘re simply not testing things correctly. ◼

> Does this mean that SHA512 only provides 511 bits of security?

No, as practically shown/proven above.

> Does this prove that SHA512 is not a random oracle?

No, as practically shown/proven above.